SQLAlchemy says my object has no attribute
My code seems running fine up until i try to call the task_change.frame attribute, where it then returns the following traceback:
`127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2024 13:23:58] "POST /auth/update_task HTTP/1.1" 500 - Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\stuar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Users\stuar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\stuar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\stuar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request    
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\stuar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request    
    rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\stuar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)   File "C:\GitHub\BMS\ITBM\auth.py", line 1301, in update_task
    print("\nROUTE:", "/update_task", "\nFRAME:", task_change.frame, "\nTASK:", task_change.desc) AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'frame'`

Here is the specific route functionality:
`@auth.route("/update_task", methods=["POST"])
def update_task():
    data = request.json
    frame = data.get("frame")
    task = data.get("task")
    print("\nROUTE:", "/update_task", "\nFRAME:", frame, "\nTASK:", task)

    task_change = db.session.query(Task).filter(Task.desc == task)
    print("\nROUTE:", "/update_task", "\nFRAME:", task_change.frame, "\nTASK:", task_change.desc)
    if task_change:
        task_change.frame = frame
        db.session.commit()
        print("Changes commited")
    else:
        print(False)
    return redirect(url_for("auth.maintenance_plan"))`

and the model for the Database is as such:
`class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    frame = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, default="monday")`

So i very clearly see a frame but cannot access it? What could be causing this? and if there are any questions that have been asked in the past relating to this id appreciate a link.

You will need either .one() or .all() as per the explanation of the linked question, though your use case probably will require .one() or .first().
